# Regular Expressions Algorithm

Tags: regex, algorithm

Given a sub-string, is there a way to generate all the possible regular expressions (most restrictive to least restrictive) that would match that sub-string for a given string?

For example, say you have a sub-string "orange" and a string "apple banana orange grape". How would I get a list of regexes that match "orange" (I know there will be a lot; hoping there is some library to do this for me already).

Comment: There are much more than "a lot", there are infinite number of regex that would any target string. A simple example is: "orange", ".*orange", ".*orange.*", ".*.*orange.*.*" ad so on. you should clarify your question, please explain what's your final goal.

Comment: Even `(any possible regex)?orange(any possibe regex)?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically the same as asking "given some runtime requirements, is there a way to generate all the possible programs (most efficient to least efficient) that would match those requirements for a given input?" The answer is *yes*, there is a *way* to do it, but the number of the results is infinite, limited only by the bounds of reasonable memory and language implementation constraints, so you'll need to impose restrictions on what constitutes a valid "program" for your purposes, in order to cut it down to a finite set.

For instance, you can restrict yourself to a specific grammar, of sorts, representing a subset of the regular expression language in question, and only generate regexes matching that grammar:

```
Regex       ::= StartAnchor? Anything? (Substring | Anything) Anything? EndAnchor?

StartAnchor ::= "^"

Anything    ::= ".*"
              | "(.*)"

Substring   ::= "orange"
              | "(orange)"

EndAnchor   ::= "$"
```

Recursively take all paths of this grammar (i.e., each branch indicated by `?` and `|`) to generate all of your target regular expressions. Of course, this answer deliberately says nothing about whether doing this is a good idea, or at all necessary...

Comment: 'This is basically the same as asking "....."' - huh? It's not the same thing and it's NOT doable. If I misunderstood you please explain what you meant.